# Could this sentence be considered correct?

Tags: past-continuous

“Those are the people who had been living in the mansion for a year.”

- The people are still alive.
- They are not living there anymore.

Comment: Welcome! We generally don't offer "proofreading" services. To help you, we'll need you to explain what part of the sentence you think may be incorrect. We also need you to explain the situation. While a great many sentences may be grammatically correct, that doesn't mean that they represent the situation you are trying to describe.

Comment: Since I have used past perfect continuous, I think I should use "were" instead of "are".

Comment: Do the people still exist/are you looking at them? Do they still live in the house? These sorts of things determine whether or not the phrase is correct **for your situation**. Please edit this info into your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Added them in...

Comment: Wise man say: _Don't use the perfect unless you have to._

Answer (score 1):

I find your question to be clear - "Could this sentence be correct?"

My answer is yes - it could be correct, if you are indicating a group of people who lived in the mansion for a year, but who are no longer living there.  However, as a native (American) English speaker, I would say the same thing this way:

"Those are the people who lived in the mansion for a year."  (same idea, less wordy).